# How to make a linear layout scrollable?

Tags: android, xml, layout, scroll

Hey all - is it possible to make an entire linear layout scrollable when it needs to be? (when all of the elements in the layout don't fit on the main screen)?

I know it is doable with views, etc...but is there a way to incorporate everything on the layout to be scrollable at the same time?

Maybe scrollable is not the right term...basically - if one of the elements (a button in this case) doesn't entirely make it onto the main screen of the phone and I need to slide a finger down to access it...if that makes sense.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A LinearLayout is a subclass of View, so anything you can do with a View you can with a Linear Layout.

So just use [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) with a single LinearLayout as a child

Answer (score 33):

Just exemplifying what the other guys are talking about

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         Here is your layout!

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can make your whole view scrollable using `ScrollView` but since you can only contain one main child so you will have to add another LinearView View inside ScrollView and put your other views inside this.

-Main View

-- ScrollView

--- LinearView

---- Sub View 1

---- Sub View 2

---- Sub View 3

....

Answer (score 2):

you can make any layout scrollable. Just under `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` add these lines:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and at the end add `</ScrollView>`

example of a non-scrollable activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    tools:context="p32929.demo.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

After making it scrollable, it becomes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
        tools:context="p32929.demo.MainActivity">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```